# HTML Array to Input field names - get Values in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have question that How to use Named Array input field. 
Because here I have a situation like each question has different kind of answers so I designed Html like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" id=""><?=$data->question?></label>
    <?php
        if (isset($data->answer)) {
            $answer = explode("|", $data->answer);
        }
    ?>
    <div class="input-container">
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="<?=$data->id?>[]" value="yes" <?=((isset($answer[0]))? (($answer[0] == "yes") ? "checked" : "" ): '' )?> >
                Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="<?=$data->id?>[]" value="no" <?=((isset($answer[0]))? (($answer[0] == "no") ? "checked" : "" ): '' )?> >
                No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="<?=$data->id?>[]" value="dont_know" <?=((isset($answer[0]))? (($answer[0] == "dont_know") ? "checked" : "" ): '' )?>  >
                Don't Know
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="<?=$data->id?>[]" value="1" <?=(isset($answer[1])=='1')?'checked':'' ?>> Check if recent change
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

like this I have Different kinds of Answer views(Here Its deals either one from radio and if it is recent change or not check box, some times both, some times anyone-- No validation wanted for this)

So here currently have "|" separated Answer blob in Database but I want to change it to JSON like if user selected (yes and checkbox) / (no radio only checkbox)/ (only radio no checkbox) `{["0"=> 'yes', "1"=>1], ["0"=> null, "1"=>1], ["0"=> 'yes', "1"=>null]}`
by this I can set the data in edit mode. So in HTML/PHP how can I get it ?

Comment: Use named Array fields on values that are likely to be entered/selected  by a user. But radio fields are used for singular value like yes/no. For multiple values use checkboxes(NamedArray field) and try to give different names to namedArray (for checkboxes) and singular fields like radio buttons, input, etc.

Comment: @Hiren Thanks for your response i changed something like this checkbox's   name="<?=$data->id?>[][checkbox]" but still what ever the values select only coming to php.. but I want if not select get null kind of

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question properly so I wrote little example code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
           echo "<pre>". json_encode($_POST) . "</pre>";
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="input-container">
        Single Value Question:
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="singleAnswer" value="yes" >
                Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="singleAnswer" value="no">
                No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="singleAnswer" value="dont_know">
                Don't Know
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
    Multiple answer question
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="array[first]" value="1" > First choice
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="array[second]" value="1" > Scond choice maybe..                
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="" name="array[third]" value="1" > I want to be null..                
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
</div>
```

- Here I added named array input fields(Collection[itemname]) for checkboxes.
- And a common name for radio buttons(Important) for single value answer.

  > However, you have to check the result of the form values that which were
  >   passed and which were not. Its possible to to validate on client-side via Javascript and there you can add null values to fields which were not selected, and then you can propogate the request to server via ajax or standard request as well. 
  >   And based on **$_POST** values you can set null to the values.